# In the class, there are $30$ students

Tags: probability, logic

I am preparing to take an entrance exam for a university in my country, which will happen soon. As part of my preparation, I have been practicing with some sample math tests provided by the university. However, I recently came across a math problem that I could not understand at all.

This is the exercise:

> In the class, there are $30$ students. One-third of them chose mathematics and physics equally at the same time. At least one of these subjects was chosen by $24$ students. $22$ students decided to graduate in English. $8$ students chose all three subjects, and only $3$ students chose mathematics. $15$ students chose mathematics and English at the same time. Two students did not choose any of these three subjects. Determine which statements are true. 
>  **(a)** There is no student who chose only physics. 
>  **(b)** This situation cannot occur. 
>  **(c)** More students chose English or physics than mathematics or physics. 
>  **(d)** Only English was chosen by more students than mathematics and physics combined. 
>  **(e)** None of the other options are correct.

---

The correct one is **(c)**, but with the procedure that I have done, it gives me that the correct answer is **(d)**. Can anyone please help me with this one? Thank you.

Comment: Please show your procedure which gives the answer as (d).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you have to use the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Comment: I suspect that there are errors in how you have written this, either due to transcription errors, translation errors, or because the original question was written poorly.  "*Only three students chose mathematics*" does not agree with "*8 students chose all three subjects.*"  That would have sounded to me like $|M|=3$ and $|M\cap E\cap P|=8$ but it is impossible for $|M|<|M\cap E\cap P|$.  This line likely should have read "*Three students chose only mathematics*" which is a very different statement.

Comment: I further suspect that the most likely source of errors you might be experiencing may be due to either the incorrectness of how some of these statements are written or due to the incorrectness of how you have interpreted these statements.  Be warned that statements like "*22 students decided to graduate in English*" should be interpreted as "22 students decided to graduate in English *and possibly additional subjects in addition to English (such as double majoring in English and Mathematics, or triple majoring in all three, etc...)*"

Comment: As others have written, the claim "only $3$ students chose mathematics" is hard to reconcile with the other claims.  Perhaps it was to read "$3$ students chose only mathematics"?  Nor do I understand what "equally at the same time" means in this context.  Does it, for instance, preclude English?  In any case, I expect that the unclear phrasing is the heart of the confusion here.

Comment: What does "chose" mean in this context? What does "One-third of them chose mathematics and physics equally at the same time." mean? Are there students who may have chosen these two subjects unequally at different times? Is there a difference between a student choosing English as opposed to graduating in English?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the set of students majoring in math (*possibly majoring in additional*), $E$ the set majoring in English, and $P$ the set majoring in physics... Let $\Omega$ be the full set of students.

I assume the conditions are meant to be interpreted as follows:

- In class there are 30 students:  $|\Omega| = 30$
- ($\star$) One-third of them chose mathematics and physics equally at the same time:  $|M\cap P|=\frac{30}{3}=10$
- ($\star$) At least one of these subjects was chosen by 24 students:  $|M|=24$ or $|E|=24$ or $|P|=24$
- 22 students decided to graduate in English: $|E|=22$
- 8 students chose all three subjects: $|M\cap E\cap P|=8$
- ($\star$) Only 3 students chose mathematics --- (3 students chose only mathematics??) ---: $|M\cap E^c\cap P^c|=3$
- 15 students chose mathematics and English at the same time: $|M\cap E|=15$
- 2 students did not choose any of these three subjects: $|M^c\cap E^c\cap P^c| = 2$

Those marked with a ($\star$) I found to be phrased rather strangely and so could have interpreted in a way different than the question author intended, however interpreting them in a different way than I had I feel contradicts other pieces of information.  For instance, if the third condition was meant to have been "*24 students chose at least one of these subjects*" that would have been $|M\cup E\cup P|=24$ but that contradicts the last condition coupled with the first since $24\neq 30-2$

---

We can start filling out a Venn Diagram for the situation.  It is typically easiest to fill from inside out.  From the fifth condition we know that $|M\cap E\cap P|=8$.  From there with the seventh condition we know $|M\cap E|=15$ at the same time which implies that $|M\cap E\cap P^c|=15-8=7$ and the sixth condition I am interpreting as $|M\cap E^c\cap P^c|=3$.

From there, the second condition how I am interpreting it implies $|M\cap P|=10$ and so $|M\cap P\cap E^c|=10-8=2$ and so we know that $|M|=3+2+8+7=20\neq 24$.  Similarly we know $|E|=22\neq 24$ thanks to the fourth condition, and so the third condition implies that $|P|=24$.

We now have almost every piece of information filled out in our Venn diagram... and so we turn our attention to finding out $|P\cap E\cap M^c|$, I'll call this value $x$.  We know that $|P\cup E|$ should equal $|\Omega|-|M^c\cap E^c\cap P^c|-|M\cap E^c\cap P^c|=30-2-3=25$.  We also know that $|P\cup E|=|P|+|E|-|P\cap E\cap M|-|P\cap E\cap M^c| = 24+22-8-x$.  This would lead us to $24+22-8-x=25$ which would lead us to $x=13$...

However, that would have $22=|E|=|E\cap P\cap M|+|E\cap P^c\cap M|+|E\cap P\cap M^c|+|E\cap P^c\cap M^c|=7+8+13+|E\cap P^c\cap M^c|$

That would have implied that $|E\cap P^c\cap M^c|=22-28=-6$ which is impossible.

I find the answer given the way the question is currently written and my interpretation of the statements to be (B) - "The situation cannot occur"

Answer (score 1):

"c" is the correct answer when the statements are interpreted a specific way.

Demonstrating in R code:

Build a `data.table` to represent the class.

```
library(data.table)
class <- data.table(
  M = rep.int(rep(1:0, 2), c(15,7,5,3)), # mathematics
  P = rep.int(rep(1:0, 4), c(8,7,3,4,2,3,1,2)), # physics
  E = c(rep(1L, 22), integer(8)), # English
  O = c(integer(28),1L,1L) # other
)
```

`M` = mathematics, `P` = physics, `E` = English, `O` = other

```
class
#>     M P E O
#>  1: 1 1 1 0
#>  2: 1 1 1 0
#>  3: 1 1 1 0
#>  4: 1 1 1 0
#>  5: 1 1 1 0
#>  6: 1 1 1 0
#>  7: 1 1 1 0
#>  8: 1 1 1 0
#>  9: 1 0 1 0
#> 10: 1 0 1 0
#> 11: 1 0 1 0
#> 12: 1 0 1 0
#> 13: 1 0 1 0
#> 14: 1 0 1 0
#> 15: 1 0 1 0
#> 16: 0 1 1 0
#> 17: 0 1 1 0
#> 18: 0 1 1 0
#> 19: 0 0 1 0
#> 20: 0 0 1 0
#> 21: 0 0 1 0
#> 22: 0 0 1 0
#> 23: 1 1 0 0
#> 24: 1 1 0 0
#> 25: 1 0 0 0
#> 26: 1 0 0 0
#> 27: 1 0 0 0
#> 28: 0 1 0 0
#> 29: 0 0 0 1
#> 30: 0 0 0 1
#>     M P E O
```

Check the 8 conditions.

```
condition <- logical(8)

# there are 30 students
condition[1] <- nrow(class) == 30
# One-third of them chose mathematics and physics equally at the same time
condition[2] <- class[,sum(M & P)/.N] == 1/3
# At least one of these subjects was chosen by 24 students
condition[3] <- class[,sum(M | P)] == 24
# 22 students decided to graduate in English
condition[4] <- class[,sum(E)] == 22
# 8 students chose all three subjects
condition[5] <- class[,sum(M & P & E)] == 8
# only 3 students chose mathematics
condition[6] <- class[,sum(M & !P & !E)] == 3
# 15 students chose mathematics and English at the same time
condition[7] <- class[,sum(M & E)] == 15
# Two students did not choose any of these three subjects
condition[8] <- class[,sum(!M & !P & !E)] == 2

condition
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Consider the answer options:

```
option <- setNames(logical(5), letters[1:5])

# There is no student who chose only physics
option[1] <- class[,sum(!M & P & !E)] == 0
# This situation cannot occur.
option[2] <- !all(condition)
# More students chose English or physics than mathematics or physics.
option[3] <- class[,sum(E | P) > sum(M | P)]
# Only English was chosen by more students than mathematics and physics combined
option[4] <- class[,sum(E) > sum(M | P) & sum(O) <= sum(M | P)]
# None of the other options are correct.
option[5] <- !any(option[-5])

option
#>     a     b     c     d     e 
#> FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

# correct answer:
names(option)[option]
#> [1] "c"
```

Comment: "*At least one of these subjects was chosen by 24 students*"  In your hypothetical scenario you had $22$ students who chose math.  You had $14$ students who chose physics.  You had $22$ students who chose english.  You failed to have an individual subject chosen by $24$.  Rather, the condition that you have written is confirming that "There are 24 people who chose --math or physics--" which is different than "There are 24 people who chose math -- or there are 24 people who chose physics"

Comment: In "At least one of these subjects was chosen by 24 students" the interpretation used here is: "these subjects" = mathematics and physics (the only two subjects introduced by that point in the problem statement; "at least one...was chosen by 24" = counting the number of students who chose mathematics or physics or both mathematics and physics (irrespective of whether any of them also chose something other than mathematics or physics) gives 24.

Comment: As I stated, the answer "c" matches only with a specific interpretation of the problem statement. The statement certainly could have been clearer, and, as written, can readily be interpreted different ways. My intention was to illustrate a perfectly plausible interpretation that results in the "correct" answer (c).

Comment: If I were to rephrase that condition to match this interpretation, it would be something like "24 students chose at least one of these two subjects (mathematics and physics)".